# Split commerce cart to multiple orders per product

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

What's a solution in Drupal Commerce to create an order per product in cart during the checkout?

**The cart looks like this:**

- Product A, Quantity: 2, $100
- Product B, Quantity: 1, $199

Total: $399

**The order-output should be:**

- Order #1: Product A, Quantity: 2, $100, Total: $200
- Order #2: Product B, Quantity: 1, $199

So instead of the usually created single order that contains all products in the cart, the goal is to create an order per product in the cart.

Could a checkout rule solve this? Or a custom module, and if, how?

Answer (score 0):

As you now,by default drupal add to cart form add all products to the same order.

Looking at the code of commerce_cart.module, the base and unique behaviour of commerce_cart module, it doesn't works in other way. When a product is add to cart, the order associated will be the same order or a new order.

If you want to decouple the line items in two different orders in cart page you will have to code a module based in commerce cart with that feature.

You can take a look to this module, it maybe helps you https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_multiple

Comment: Thanks, Omar. I've checked the Cart Multiple, but as far as i can say, it takes the same problem to multiple instances and confuses the end-user. I've had a Checkout rule with a loop in mind, but I don't know if that works.